# switch back to clang after installing gcc through Macports on Mavericks

Tags: macos, xcode, macports, gcc

After I installed Macports (and after that I have installed several versions of gcc through Macports), whenever I type gcc, one of those gcc installed through Macports will be invoked.

Before I installed Macports, whenever I type gcc, clang that comes with XCode will be invoked. (not sure this is true)

Now I need to compile a 3rd-party package with clang, but I don't know how I should do.

**My question** is: now that Macports (w gcc48) has been installed, what should I do to switch back to the setting where gcc is linked to clang that comes with XCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

find the line that looks like this:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

comment it out by putting `#` in front of it.

Comment: That will exclude every bin install by Macport ... Definitely not the best idea.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to avoid uninstalling or changing your PATH. Just run:

```
sudo port select --set gcc none
```

…and to re-enable it you run:

```
sudo port select --set gcc gcc5
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove it from your `$PATH`.

One off your possibilites is to just uninstall it : `sudo port uninstall gcc`